# jQuery datetimepicker addon not working when attached to div rather than input element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using the jquery Trent Richardson datetimepicker addon which is working fine when linked to a text input (see link below).

http://jsfiddle.net/many_tentacles/xnn3M/1/

However, when I attach it to a div so that the picker shows all the time, and an altField option, the date and time do not display correctly in the altfield (see link below). I can create a similar problem if I add an altField to the version that works so I think it might have something to do with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/many_tentacles/EyPm5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya please see **working demo here**: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgnjn/

D'uh don't forget to upvote and accept :))

You can use the onSelect event:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    //altField: '#alternate',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
    stepHour: 2,
    stepMinute: 10,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method

        $('#alternate').val(dateAsObject);
       // alert(dateAsObject + '==> ' + $('#alternate').val());
   }

});
```

The first parameter is in this case the selected Date as String. Use [parseDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) to convert it to a JS Date Object.

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker for the full jQuery UI DatePicker reference.